# How to find the $20$ consecutive composite numbers

Tags: number-theory

I have a little confusion over the following problem:

> Find the $20$ consecutive composite numbers.

HINTS:  $$\color {green} {\text{Numbers}\,\, 20!+2,20!+3,\cdots ,20!+21 \,\,\text{will do the trick. The following result by Euclid has been known for more than 2000 years.}}$$

But the solution is not very clear to me specially I do not understand why $k$  has been added to $20!$ where the numbers are of the form $20!+k,k=2....,21$.

Can someone explain it? Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: You could use $19!$ instead of $20!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every natural number $n$, if $k\le n$ is a natural number, then $k\mid n!+k$ (simply since $k\mid n!$). In particular, if $1<k\le n$, then $n!+k$ is not prime. It follows that all of $n!+2,n!+3,\cdots ,n!+n$ are composite. Thus, for every $n$ you can find a list of $n-1$ consecutive composite numbers.

This should explain how the result you quote was arrived at (you just need to notice that $20!+21$ is also composite.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that for each $k \in \{2,\ldots,20\}$, $k$ divides $20!$ and $k$ divides $k$, so $k$ divides their sum. Hence, $20!+k$ is composite.

For the case where $k=21$, simply observe that:
$$
20! = (20) \cdot \ldots \cdot (7) \cdot \ldots \cdot (3) \ldots \cdot (1)
$$
Hence, since $21 \mid 20!$ and $21 \mid 21$, it follows that $20! + 21$ is also composite.

Comment: Thanks @Adriano for the nice explanation.

Comment: Note also that $20!+22$ is composite